# Inserting automatically generated UIView objects in a mutable array

Tags: iphone, uiview, nsmutablearray

I

I wrote a function which generates 6 UIView object automatically (with iteration), and I try then to insert each object in a NSMutableArray, but when I run it, it stop with warning (without a reference to the bug).

I dont know what is not conform in my logical steps.

here is my code.

```
-(void)initierScrollView
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
        UIImageView *bouton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [bouton setTag:i];
        classementBoutons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:40];
        [bouton setFrame:CGRectMake(10+62*i,10,62,55)];
        [classementBoutons insertObject:bouton atIndex:i];
        bouton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
        recognizer.delegate = self; 
        [bouton addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


       // NSLog(@"%@", classementBoutons.description);


        [self addSubview:bouton];
}
}
```

thank you for your responses

Victor

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Comment: It comes back to main function and with a SIGABRT received signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You creating new NSMutableArray on each loop iteration.
Try to create it only once before loop.